# Images are not showing in Google DFP

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, safari, internet-explorer-9, google-dfp

I'm new to Google DoubleClick for Publishers.

I have created the test HTML pages and images are not showing on the page (from my machine and my test server). I checked in Firefox, Chrome, IE9, Safari.
I tried the javascript code generated from "Generate tags" button, and [THIS](https://github.com/coop182/jquery.dfp.js) DFP jQuery library.

Also, I found some test HTML pages from [HERE](https://github.com/coop182/jquery.dfp.js/issues/8) and they are running+showing the images from my machine and my test server.

I test the page in DFP Consol and I'm getting **Page tagged correctly!**
See this image (Getting same in Chrome, Firefox, IE9, and Safari):

[image: Getting same in Chrome, Firefox, IE9, and Safari]

Now from [THIS](https://github.com/coop182/jquery.dfp.js/issues/6) thread I understand that **"This is usually caused by not having enough ad inventory in dfp"**.

So please let me know how to create enough ad inventory in dfp?

My test page HTML is [HERE](http://pastebin.com/FncD4iRv).

Thanks
Kapil

Comment: Where is your test page sorry?

Comment: I'm sorry Matt. You can get the test page HTML from http://pastebin.com/FncD4iRv .

Comment: The ads are loading for me in New Zealand... which country are you in and are you using geo-targeting, or is the ad network you are using doing geo targeting? Perhaps double check by using a proxy from a different country.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matt, Thanks for your help. It worked for me too. Actually, when I created the Line Item I set the **Type = House** (Lowest-ranking line item type), as I set the **Type = Network** it started working.